# How to compare dates in Java?

Tags: java, date, comparison

How do I compare dates in between in Java?

Example:

date1 is `22-02-2010`
 date2 is `07-04-2010` today 
 date3 is `25-12-2010`

`date3` is always greater than `date1` and `date2` is always today. How do I verify if today's date is in between date1 and date 3?

Answer (score 688, accepted):

[Date](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) has [before](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)) and [after](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)) methods and can be [compared to each other](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)) as follows:

```
if(todayDate.after(historyDate) && todayDate.before(futureDate)) {
    // In between
}
```

For an inclusive comparison:

```
if(!historyDate.after(todayDate) && !futureDate.before(todayDate)) {
    /* historyDate <= todayDate <= futureDate */ 
}
```

You could also give [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) a go, but note that:

> Joda-Time is the *de facto* standard date and time library for Java prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) ([JSR-310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)).

Back-ports are available for Java 6 and 7 as well as Android.

Comment: Is this inclusive, or exclusive for the borders?

Comment: @DanielHári no its not inclusive.  you can use the solution suggested  in the first comment , or use CompareTo()>=0 .

Comment: The normal usually "left inclusive, right exclusive", this why I think this should be specified exactly. With "left inclusive, right exclusive" borders, you can specify fe: a month interval easily: [2016/04/01, 2016/05/01], this why this is the normal and used as default in many use cases.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque yes, correct, hence the remarks about Joda and `java.time` for Java 8, which is now the standard version (contrary to the time I wrote this answer). Feel free to edit this answer and add more recent example code, of course! ;) (EDIT: ah, I see you yourself already provided an answer with said examples)

Answer (score 147):

Use [compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo-java.util.Date-):

`date1.compareTo(date2);`

Comment: Works perfect with Date, Byte, Long, Integer...

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't work. I triggered multiple times using in a main method to check equality. Most of the times it says equal, but not all times.

Comment: @Syed Can you share your code?

Comment: @ChandraSekarS, try to execute as a main method code by taking same dates and see the output. Sometimes, it gives 0 and sometimes 1.

Answer (score 131):

Following are most common way of comparing `dates` (my preference is **Approach 1**):

**Approach 1: Using `Date.before()`, `Date.after()` and `Date.equals(`)**

```
if (date1.after(date2)) {
    System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");
}

if (date1.before(date2)) {
    System.out.println("Date1 is before Date2");
}

if (date1.equals(date2)) {
    System.out.println("Date1 is equal Date2");
}
```

**Approach 2: `Date.compareTo()`**

```
if (date1.compareTo(date2) > 0) {
    System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");
} else if (date1.compareTo(date2) < 0) {
    System.out.println("Date1 is before Date2");
} else {
    System.out.println("Date1 is equal to Date2");
}
```

**Approach 3:  `Calendar.before()`, `Calendar.after(`) and `Calendar.equals()`**

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTime(date1);
cal2.setTime(date2);

if (cal1.after(cal2)) {
    System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");
}

if (cal1.before(cal2)) {
    System.out.println("Date1 is before Date2");
}

if (cal1.equals(cal2)) {
    System.out.println("Date1 is equal Date2");
}
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: compareTo method may give a sporadic issue. better to use another way

Answer (score 43):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
Boolean isBetween = 
    ( ! today.isBefore( localDate1 ) )  // “not-before” is short for “is-equal-to or later-than”.
    &&
    today.isBefore( localDate3 ) ;
```

Or, better, if you add the *ThreeTen-Extra* library to your project.

```
LocalDateRange.of(
    LocalDate.of( … ) ,
    LocalDate.of( … )
).contains(
    LocalDate.now()
)
```

Half-open approach, where beginning is *inclusive* while ending is *exclusive*.

## Bad Choice of Format

By the way, that is a bad choice of format for a text representation of a date or date-time value. Whenever possible, stick with the standard [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. ISO 8601 formats are unambiguous, understandable across human cultures, and are easy to parse by machine.

For a date-only value, the standard format is YYYY-MM-DD. Note how this format has the benefit of being chronological when sorted alphabetically.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

## `DateTimeFormatter`

As your input strings are non-standard format, we must define a formatting pattern to match.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" );
```

Use that to parse the input strings.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( "22-02-2010" , f );
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.parse( "25-12-2010" , f );
```

In date-time work, usually best to define a span of time by the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So we want to know if today is the same or later than the start and also before the stop. A briefer way of saying “is the same or later than the start” is “not before the start”.

```
Boolean intervalContainsToday = ( ! today.isBefore( start ) ) && today.isBefore( stop ) ;
```

See [the Answer by gstackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33693122/642706) showing the list of comparison methods you can call.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

UPDATE: This “Joda-Time” section below is left intact as history. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## Joda-Time

Other answers are correct with regard to the bundled java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar classes. But those classes are notoriously troublesome. So here's some example code using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library.

If you truly want a date without any time portion and no time zone, then use the [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class in Joda-Time. That class provides methods of comparison including `compareTo` (used with [Java Comparators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)), `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `isEqual`.

Inputs…

```java
String string1 = "22-02-2010";
String string2 = "07-04-2010";
String string3 = "25-12-2010";
```

Define a formatter describing the input strings…

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy" );
```

Use formatter to parse the strings into LocalDate objects…

```java
LocalDate localDate1 = formatter.parseLocalDate( string1 );
LocalDate localDate2 = formatter.parseLocalDate( string2 );
LocalDate localDate3 = formatter.parseLocalDate( string3 );

boolean is1After2 = localDate1.isAfter( localDate2 );
boolean is2Before3 = localDate2.isBefore( localDate3 );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "Dates: " + localDate1 + " " + localDate2 + " " + localDate3 );
System.out.println( "is1After2 " + is1After2 );
System.out.println( "is2Before3 " + is2Before3 );
```

When run…

```
Dates: 2010-02-22 2010-04-07 2010-12-25
is1After2 false
is2Before3 true
```

So see if the second is between the other two (exclusively, meaning not equal to either endpoint)…

```
boolean is2Between1And3 = ( ( localDate2.isAfter( localDate1 ) ) && ( localDate2.isBefore( localDate3 ) ) );
```

## Working With Spans Of Time

If you are working with spans of time, I suggest exploring in Joda-Time the classes: [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html), [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html), and [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html). Methods such as `overlap` and `contains` make comparisons easy.

For text representations, look at the ISO 8601 standard’s:

- [duration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)
  Format: PnYnMnDTnHnMnS
  Example: P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S
  (Means “three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds”)
- [interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals)
  Format: start/end
  Example: 2007-03-01T13:00:00Z/2008-05-11T15:30:00Z

Joda-Time classes can work with strings in both those formats, both as input (parsing) and output (generating strings).

Joda-Time performs comparisons using the **Half-Open** approach where the beginning of the span is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This approach is a wise one for handling spans of time. Search StackOverflow for more info.

Comment: Excellent practice-tip to mention the [(right) _half-open_ interval](https://wcipeg.com/wiki/Half-open_interval) approach for the predicate "is inside a time span".

Answer (score 23):

Compare the two dates:

```
  Date today = new Date();                   
  Date myDate = new Date(today.getYear(),today.getMonth()-1,today.getDay());
  System.out.println("My Date is"+myDate);    
  System.out.println("Today Date is"+today);
  if (today.compareTo(myDate)<0)
      System.out.println("Today Date is Lesser than my Date");
  else if (today.compareTo(myDate)>0)
      System.out.println("Today Date is Greater than my date"); 
  else
      System.out.println("Both Dates are equal");
```

Comment: I think that "new Date(today.getYear(),today.getMonth()-1,today.getDay());" it's deprecated.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: @Muath: Although I am not 100 % sure, I think it is because the month component in `Date` is zero-indexed.

Comment: i think in there else part is not working :)

Answer (score 15):

## Update for Java 8 and later

- [`isAfter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-)
- [`isBefore()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-)
- [`isEqual()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isEqual-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-)
- [`compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#compareTo-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-)

These methods exists in [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html), and [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) classes.

Those classes are built into Java 8 and later. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

Comment: how to download these three classes

Comment: @Punithapriya These classes exists in java 8 standart library. Thus just download java 8

Comment: yes i have seen thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`Date.getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) which:

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
>   represented by this Date object.

This means you can compare them just like numbers:

```
if (date1.getTime() <= date.getTime() && date.getTime() <= date2.getTime()) {
    /*
     * date is between date1 and date2 (both inclusive)
     */
}

/*
 * when date1 = 2015-01-01 and date2 = 2015-01-10 then
 * returns true for:
 * 2015-01-01
 * 2015-01-01 00:00:01
 * 2015-01-02
 * 2015-01-10
 * returns false for:
 * 2014-12-31 23:59:59
 * 2015-01-10 00:00:01
 * 
 * if one or both dates are exclusive then change <= to <
 */
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
public static boolean compareDates(String psDate1, String psDate2) throws ParseException{
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(psDate1);
        Date date2 = dateFormat.parse(psDate2);
        if(date2.after(date1)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use getTime() to get the numeric value of the date, and then compare using the returned values.

Answer (score 0):

This code determine today is in some duration.. based on KOREA locale

```
    Calendar cstart = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.KOREA);
    cstart.clear();
    cstart.set(startyear, startmonth, startday);


    Calendar cend = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.KOREA);
    cend.clear();
    cend.set(endyear, endmonth, endday);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.KOREA);

    if(c.after(cstart) && c.before(cend)) {
        // today is in startyear/startmonth/startday ~ endyear/endmonth/endday
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me:

```
 public static String daysBetween(String day1, String day2) {
    String daysBetween = "";
    SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    try {
        Date date1 = myFormat.parse(day1);
        Date date2 = myFormat.parse(day2);
        long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
        daysBetween = ""+(TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return daysBetween;
}
```

Comment: Does not answer the Question. The Question involves *three* dates, not two. “How do I verify if today's date is in between date1 and date 3?” Furthermore, this calculation returns the number of 24-hour periods, not the number of calendar days elapsed. Yet another problem: This answer uses date-time values while the Question is about date-only values without time-of-day.