# How to compare between two dates in java?

Tags: java, swing, date, jtable, compare

Passing my salute to every single hard working developer,

and cheers to every struggler out there.

Actually i am here because i got stuck on a very basic problem.

I am building a client-server application, and i am confused about how to compare between two dates extracted from jtable (eventually i've never got across any operations on dates in general).

I've used this code:

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "yyyy-MM-dd";

  public static String now() {
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
   return sdf.format(cal.getTime());

   }

 public static void ColorTheCell2(JTable jTable2){
          jTable2.getColumn("Date d'expiration").setCellRenderer(
    new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

        @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent
    (JTable table,Object value,boolean isSelected,boolean hasFocus,int row,int column){

    Calendar datetable=Calendar.getInstance();

    String date=value.toString();
    String day=""+date.substring(8).toString();
    String month=""+date.substring(5, 7).toString();
    String year=""+date.substring(0,4).toString();

   datetable.set(Integer.parseInt(year),Integer.parseInt(month),Integer.parseInt(day));
    Calendar curdate=Calendar.getInstance();

     String date1=now();
     String day1=""+date1.substring(8).toString();
     String month1=""+date1.substring(5, 7).toString();
     String year1=""+date1.substring(0,4).toString();
                curdate.set(Integer.parseInt(year1),Integer.parseInt(month1)+1,Integer.parseInt(day1));


            if(datetable.before(curdate)){

                setText(value.toString());
                setBackground(Color.red);
            }
            else{
                 setText(value.toString());
            }

return this;
 }
  });
    }
```

Thank you for your Time.
Best regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/compare-dates-in-java

Comment: Your code is very difficult to read, due to wildly inconsistent formatting. Don't make it difficult for people to help you.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  (As opposed to expanding the code snippets.)  And please indent the code more logically.

Answer (score 6):

You don't tell what the type of the value in the cell is. If it's a String, then you're doing it wrong: it should be a Date, and the renderer should use a `DateFormat` to render the date (in addition to setting the appropriate background. This will, for example, allow sorting the table chronologically rather than lexicographically.

If it's already a Date, then just compare it with the current date, using its compareTo method.

Your now() method is really strange, since it seems to return a String rather than a Date. The appropriate type to represent a date is Date, not String. Use a Date and format it using a DateFormat each time you need it as a String. Don't do the reverse (using a String and parsing it - manually - each time you need a Date).

Comment: +1 for the extensive explanation. Nitpicking (obviously a matter of taste, that is mine :-) - prefer domain specific api over general, that is before/after over compareTo.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [`compareTo()` in Calendar class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo%28java.util.Calendar%29)

In general , I prefer using Joda Time API for dates and time related stuff in java.

Answer (score 4):

If in `Object value` value is of type `Date` then cast it to `Date` -

```
Date valDate = (Date) value;
```

Or, if it's `String` then parse `Date` out of it -

```
Date valDate = new SimpleDateFormat("pattern in value").parse((String) value);
```

Get current date -

```
Date currDate = new Date();
```

And then you can use any of the following methods in `Date` class -

1. `boolean after(Date when)`
2. `boolean before(Date when)`
3. `int compareTo(Date anotherDate)`

e.g.

```
if(valDate.before(currDate)) {

    //...
```

API doc: [Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/), [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 3):

`Date` implements the `Comparable` interface, therefore you can use the method [compareTo()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29) to compare between two dates. Same thing for `Calendar`, just use its [compareTo()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo%28java.util.Calendar%29) method