# Display log file names from a start date to end date

Tags: java

I need to display log files in a folder, which has date and time appended to the file name ,from a particular start date to a particular end date .how would I do that
please help.

Comment: can you please provide any clue how should the file name looks like?

Comment: You could use String#compareTo to compare the filenames with the two bounds.

Comment: LOG'BLK15_WP8_rev1'625'2014-09-15_17-08-05.130'WP8-BW05_RtHp'CW'3182713.xml

Comment: in the above file name 2014-09-15{yyyy-mm-dd) is date and 17-08-05(hh-mm-ss) is time

Comment: please help me solve this program

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the list of files in the folder containing the logs, filtering out any files that are outside of the given date-time range; this sounds exactly like a job for the [FileFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html?is-external=true) API as another answerer too pointed out:

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(myFileFilterObject);
```

Now your problem is to code the accept method of your filter.

1. If you want a quick and dirty solution, you could just use `String.CompareTo` to exploit simple string comparison (this requires your log files to be formatted as the year followed by the month as a number, then the date and finally the time).
2. If you are familiar with Regular Expressions you could reuse Apache Commons' `RegexFileFilter`, but then you would have [two problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).
3. *Or*, you could do it the 'right' way (which might be too heavy-handed for your particular purpose, though) by extracting the relevant parts of the filename and comparing the dates as mentioned in [Comparing date strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609596/comparing-date-strings-in-java):

> [Date](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) has [before](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)) and [after](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)) methods and can be [compared to each other](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)).
>
> You could also give [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) a go.
>
> > How do I verify if today's date is in between date1 and date 3?
>
> ```
> if(todayDate.after(historyDate) && todayDate.before(futureDate)) {
>     // In between
> }
> ```

Comment: @user4268406 Your logs are formatted in the right way for #1 to work. Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the files from your log directory

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

The above will give you all the files, However to meet your expectation you could use [FileFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html?is-external=true).  and now the listing code would be :

```
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(myFileFilterObject);
```

in your file filter `accept` API you define you logic to filter the files on the basis of date time range.
Or if you are good at Regex then use Apache commons `RegexFileFilter`