# Using >= and <= in Java with Strings

Tags: java, string

I want to extract people born between two years.

Being `year1 = "1990"` and `year2 = "2000"`. It seems that `>=` and `<=` doesn't work.

**How can I compare these two date strings?**

```
static void annesCom(Personne[] pers, int nbElem, String year1, String year2)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < nbElem; i++)
        if(perso[i].year() >= year1 && perso[i].year() <= year2 )
    System.out.printf("Person %d) Born in %s\n", i, pers[i].year());
}
```

Comment: Convert to integer first...

Comment: Since we're actually more talking about dates, instead of numeric values, maybe use the Date (or a Date) class and use compareTo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing date strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609596/comparing-date-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the `<=` and `>=` operators on `String`s (or `<` and `>`).  While you can use `==` and `!=` on `Strings`, [the results won't be what you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

For a numeric quantity, you shouldn't use the `String` datatype.  In your `Personne` class, change the datatype of the variable that holds the year attribute to `int`, and the return datatype of the getter method `year()` to `int` as well.  You can use `<=`, `>=`, `<`, `>`, `==`, and `!=` on `int` values.

In your `annesCom` method, accept `int` values for `year1` and `year2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `compareTo` method. But I suggest to parse string as integer with `Integer.parseInt` method and then do a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

[Parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) the numbers currently contained in strings:

```
if(perso[i].year() >= Integer.parseInt(year1) && perso[i].year() <= Integer.parseInt(year2) )
```

The only comparison operator applicable to strings in Java is `==`. This checks for reference equality (meaning it will only return `true` if the strings compared are in fact the same object). This will only yield `true` for strings with identical content known at compile time, as Java saves space by pointing them to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your String year into `Integer.parseInt()`, and then compare the integers with `>=` and `<=`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use >= or <= for a String value. String are different from other primitive values like int, double etc. You can convert String to integer and then compare it by using >= or <=

You modified code will look like this:

```
static void annesCom(Personne[] pers, int nbElem, String year1, String year2)
{
    int i;
    int year1Int = Integer.parseInt(year1);
    int year2Int = Integer.parseInt(year2);

    for(i = 0; i < nbElem; i++)
    {
        if(perso[i].year() >= year1Int && perso[i].year() <= year2Int)
        {
           System.out.printf("Person %d) Born in %s\n", i, pers[i].year());
        }
    }
}
```