# Date Comparison In Java

Tags: java, date

I have a date [format - dd/mm/yyyy]. I need to compare it with the current date so that I can execute this logic

```
if(end date is in the future) {
//logic
} else {
//logic
}
```

Can we do this in JAVA ?

Comment: This can help you: "Compare dates in Java": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/compare-dates-in-java

Comment: There is an endless amount of material on this subject.

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort. At all.

Comment: The simple answer to your actual question *Can we do this in JAVA?* is Yes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are starting with a string so you can use [SimpleDateFormat.parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) to convert the String to a Date.

Then you can use the [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29) function on the Date class to see if it is in the past or not.

Something like the below (I havent compiled this...)

```
if (new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy").parse(yourSring).compareTo(new Date()) > 0) {
   ...
}
```

If possible I would always use JodaTime thought instead of the Java Date and Calendar classes. It is much easier to use.

Comment: You can use Date#after(Date) instead of compareTo to shorten the code somewhat. And why is "DateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")).isAfterNow()" with Joda (or is it possible to do the same with shorter code?) much easier than "new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(s).after(new Date())" with the builtin API?

Answer (score 0):

In general, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/):

```
DateTime.parse("...").isAfterNow();
```

You will probably want to pass an appropriate `DateTimeFormatter`, such as `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d/M/y")`, as the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

use compareto method to compare two dates. 
check here in [Date API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

```
if(curreDate.compareTo(thisdate)>0) {
// do your logic
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(endDate.after(new Date())){}
```

just compare to a new Date it will be created a date time of now.