# Compare 2 dates

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compare dates in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/compare-dates-in-java)

I need compare two dates date1 and date2, the condition is:

1. date1 < date2
2. date1 + 14Month <= date2

For the first condition im using if(date2.after(date1))

But for the second I'm not sure...

I'm using       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(fecha1);
            calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, +14);
            Date nuevaFecha1 = (Date) calendar.getTime();

some idea how validate this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, month );
    calendar1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);  

    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    calendar2.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.MONTH, month );
    calendar2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day); 

    long mills1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
    long mills2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();

    if(mills1 > mills2){

    }else{
    }
```

Comment: Month range is 0-11 ,suppose now january so its no is 0 + 14 = 14 ,means 1 yr + 3 month so u want to add like year +1 and month 3