# comparing the two times is greater or lesser in java

Tags: java, datetime

```
  Date date1= new java.util.Date();
                  java.sql.Date Sqldob = new java.sql.Date(date1.getTime());
                  System.out.println("date" +Sqldob);

                  Time Sqldob1 = new Time(date1.getTime());
                  System.out.println("User Time: " +Sqldob1);
                  String yourTime="09:30:00"; 

                  SimpleDateFormat ra = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                  Date yourDate = ra.parse(yourTime);
                  Time sqlTime3 = new Time(yourDate.getTime());
                  System.out.println("your time"+sqlTime3);

                  if(Sqldob1.before(sqlTime3)){
                     Sqldob1 = sqlTime3; 
                     System.out.println("inside loop");
                  }
```

In the code above I am comparing two time variables for equality, but it is giving me the same value -1 for all the types of input

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/compare-dates-in-java

Comment: as per your code it just can return -1 for **one** type of input: `sqlTime3.compareTo(Sqldob1)` since it's the only place where you make the comparison. besides, please, be kind and shows also what are the potential values for `Sqldob1`...

Comment: sqldob1 will be given from user that is from java.util.date it may vary above or below 9:30:00 thnk u

Comment: can anyone plz help me out for the above code

Comment: To the usage: a loop is something that can repeat. An `if` statement cannot repeat in itself, so it is not a loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the [Date#before(Date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29),[Date#after(Date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29) and [Date#equals(Date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) methods for basic date comparisons.

**E.g:**

```
Date d1 = new Date();
Date d2 = new Date();

if(d1.after(d2)){
    // Do something
}

if(d1.before(d2)){
    // Do something
}

if(d1.equals(d2)){
    // Do something
}
```

You can use the [Date#compareTo(Date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29) method also, but then, you need to interpret the output of the `compareTo` method accordingly.

As the docs say:

> The value 0 if the argument Date is equal to this Date; a value less
>   than 0 if this Date is before the Date argument; and a value greater
>   than 0 if this Date is after the Date argument.

In your case, you are getting `-1` because

1. `new SimpleDateFormat("HHH:mm:ss");` is wrong. Should be new `SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");`
2. `int compare= sqlTime3.compareTo(Sqldob1);` This sqlTime3 has only time in it. The date is the epoch date as you've not mentioned that, and hence, its always going to be before `new Date()` which is **today**.

**Your solution:-** (Hope this addresses your problem)

```
java.util.Date date1= new java.util.Date();

Time Sqldob1 = new Time(date1.getTime());
System.out.println("User Time: " +Sqldob1);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19); // Your hour
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30); // Your Mintue
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00); // Your second

Time sqlTime3 = new Time(cal.getTime().getTime());
System.out.println("your time: "+sqlTime3);

if(Sqldob1.before(sqlTime3)){
   Sqldob1 = sqlTime3; 
   System.out.println("inside loop");
}
```

Comment: thnk u plz helping me

Comment: Look at my answer. I've editing to show a couple of problems in your code and why you're getting `-1` always.

Comment: can u plz explain here am giving only the constant time as sqltime3 it is not comparing properly can u plz assist me

Comment: SimpleDateFormat ra = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

Comment: @user2767354 - look at the point 2. You've not mentioned any date at all. That's why the epoch date is taken by default.

Comment: can u plz tell me that time wht am comparing is constant time 09:30:00 but the date will vary every day how can mention the date in it than k u

Comment: hi can plz help me in it

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? What do you want to achieve with it? You have to tell that, else its really not clear what you want to compare?!

Comment: just i want to compare the sqldob1 that is from user when login with sqltime3 that i have taken that as manually i.e 09:30:00 if sqldob1 is less than 09:30 i want to enter my time as 09:30:00 otherwise i will enter sqldob1 time to database 
 thats it ...thnk u

Comment: @user2767354 - Look at my edit! I hope it helps you solve this!

Comment: thnk u i will check it

Comment: hi i'm sorry that above code is also not working can u plz plz check once i will updated my code now thnk u

Comment: control will not enter inside the loop itself

Comment: Obviously it won't cuz the current time now is past 9:30. Try to change the 9:30 to 19:30 and then run the code. It'll enter the `if` block.

Comment: here i'm changing my system timings can u plz explain me whts wrong in it

Comment: Don't change that. Change this static time and check.

Comment: even that also i done it.Can u plz tell me is there any mistakes in my above code thnk u

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the date and call methods like `before()`, `after()` and `equals()`  like this,

```
if(date.before(date1)){
    System.out.println(" date is before date1 ");
}
if(date.after(date1)){
    System.out.println(" date is after date1 ");
}
```

If both `date` and `date1` are equal you can use equals method,

```
if(date.equals(date1)){
    System.out.println(" date and date1 are equal");
}
```

Comment: thnk u for helping me

Comment: You're welcome..cheers.. if it helped, mark the answer as accepted. (Tick below the vote counter)

Answer (score 1):

Modern version:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    LocalDate dob = dateTime1.toLocalDate();
    System.out.println("date " + dob);

    LocalTime dob1 = dateTime1.toLocalTime();
    System.out.println("User Time: " + dob1);

    String yourTime = "09:30:00"; 
    LocalTime time3 = LocalTime.parse(yourTime);
    System.out.println("your time " + time3);

    if (dob1.isBefore(time3)) {
        dob1 = time3;
        System.out.println("inside if statement");
    }
```

When I ran this code this morning, it printed:

```
date 2017-07-07
User Time: 05:32:01.881
your time 09:30
inside if statement
```

The point is: With the old and now long outdated classes `Date` and `Time` it is easy *not* to get things right. With the modern classes I use here, it’s much easier to *get* them right.

Are you using `java.sql` types because you really need to get your date and time from a database and/or store them into one? This was what these were for, you shouldn’t really have used them for other purposes. I use “was” and “were” intentionally because you don’t need them for this purpose either anymore. With a new JDBC driver, you can get a `LocalDateTime` from the database and store one back, or depending on your column datatype get an `Instant` and convert it to `LocalDateTime`:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime2 = instantFromDb.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toLocalDateTime();
```

PS Item 2. in [SoduRahul’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19046237/5772882) gives the real and correct explanation of what went wrong in your program: though `Time` was meant for time-of-day only, your `Sqldob1` ends up holding today’s date and `sqlTime3` the date of the epoch (January 1, 1970), so the former will always be after the latter by their `before` method.

Answer (score 0):

`compareTo()` method always return zero for equal and non-zero for unequal dates.