# Check variable, get next variable, check variable etc

Tags: java, variables

The purpose of the program I'm making is to check dates and if the date has passed it should show the next date.

For example, todays date is 14/10/2013. The next episode of How I Met Your Mother is today, and the one after that is 11/11/2013.

I want to program to show the date 14/10/2013, but tomorrow it should show 11/11/2013. Here is what I have:

```
public class CheckSeries {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        SimpleDateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date today = new Date();
        System.out.println(d.format(today));

        try {        // Here is where I add the times. I know it's not the most productive way, but one step at a time
            Date d0 = d.parse("14/10/2013");
            Date d1 = d.parse("11/11/2013");
            Date etc = d.parse("etc/etc/etc");

    }
}
```

So, I need it to check d0, if it is before *today* it should check d1, then d2 etc etc. But if say, d1 is after *today* it should just show d1 in a JFrame (which I know how to do, ill add the Jframe later)  But I don't know how to do that. (I think).

Comment: The similar question: Have a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/compare-dates-in-java

Comment: @Zahand you could keep all 'dx' (d0,d1.. ) variables in a list and iterate through each one calling today.compareTo(dx), the first dx that gives -1 or 0 is the correct next series day.

Comment: Not to get ahead of yourself, but you should probably load the dates from an external file, parse them, then add them into a list and delete the items off the list when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to loop over your dates comparing with current date. 
You could use [myDate.after(now)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29) to determine, if `myDate` is in future.

`Date now = new Date() //current timestamp`

and looping:

```
for (Date d : Arrays.asList(d0, d1, etc)) { //comparing here}
```