# How to compare two dates along with time in java

Tags: java, datetime, compare

I have two **`Date`** objects with the below format.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
String matchDateTime = sdf.parse("2014-01-16T10:25:00");
Date matchDateTime = null;

try {
    matchDateTime = sdf.parse(newMatchDateTimeString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// get the current date
Date currenthDateTime = null;
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date dt = new Date();
String currentDateTimeString = dateFormat.format(dt);
Log.v("CCCCCurrent DDDate String is:", "" + currentDateTimeString);

try {                   
    currenthDateTime = sdf.parse(currentDateTimeString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now  I want to compare the above two dates along with time. 
How should I compare in Java.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare dates in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Since `Date` implements `Comparable<Date>`, it is as easy as:

```
date1.compareTo(date2);
```

As the `Comparable` contract stipulates, it will return a negative integer/zero/positive integer if `date1` is considered less than/the same as/greater than `date2` respectively (ie, before/same/after in this case).

Note that `Date` has also `.after()` and `.before()` methods which will return booleans instead.

Comment: Can I somehow get the duration. Something like 2 days or 16 hours...something like that using the `comapreTo` method?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava no you can't; you'll have to diff the milliseconds. You can use `TimeUnit` to help you "fractionize" the resulting difference afterwards

Answer (score 9):

An Alternative is....

Convert both dates into milliseconds as below

```
Date d = new Date();
long l = d.getTime();
```

Now compare both long values

Answer (score 6):

Use [**`compareTo()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29)

**Return Values**

0 if the argument Date is equal to this Date; a value less than 0 if this Date is before the Date argument; and a value greater than 0 if this Date is after the Date argument.

**Like**

```
if(date1.compareTo(date2)>0)
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Use DateTime

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(new Date());
date.isBeforeNow();
or
date.isAfterNow();
```

Comment: This is also available in Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

```
 // Get calendar set to the current date and time
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

// Set time of calendar to 18:00
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

// Check if current time is after 18:00 today
boolean afterSix = Calendar.getInstance().after(cal);

if (afterSix) {
    System.out.println("Go home, it's after 6 PM!");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Hello!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are generally correct and all outdated. Do use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. With java.time your job has also become a lot easier compared to the situation when this question was asked in February 2014.

```
    String dateTimeString = "2014-01-16T10:25:00";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString);
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    if (dateTime.isBefore(now)) {
        System.out.println(dateTimeString + " is in the past");
    } else if (dateTime.isAfter(now)) {
        System.out.println(dateTimeString + " is in the future");
    } else {
        System.out.println(dateTimeString + " is now");
    }
```

When running in 2020 output from this snippet is:

> 2014-01-16T10:25:00 is in the past

Since your string doesn’t inform of us any time zone or UTC offset, we need to know what was understood. The code above uses the device’ time zone setting. For a known time zone use like for example `ZoneId.of("Asia/Ulaanbaatar")`. For UTC specify `ZoneOffset.UTC`.

I am exploiting the fact that your string is in ISO 8601 format. The classes of java.time parse the most common ISO 8601 variants without us having to give any formatter.

### Question: For Android development doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)