# Date and Time compare today in Android

Tags: android, datetime, compare, simpledateformat, datetime-comparison

```
    dateTime_form_api = "2020/02/11 10:23 AM";

    dateTime_from_system = "2020/02/11 13:00 PM";
```

I want to compare dateTime_form_api and dateTime_from_system

if dateTime_from_system after dateTime_form_api show "Next time"

if dateTime_from_system before dateTime_form_api show "Last time"

but if dateTime_form_api's date equals dateTime_from_system's date

only time need to compare , time's sompare, how to do in Android ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare two dates along with time in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039991/how-to-compare-two-dates-along-with-time-in-java)

Comment: [I downvoted because research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/). This has been asked and answered with variations very, very many times before. Please show some effort in searching when you ask a new question about the same.

Answer (score 0):

This code below maybe help you, if you want to count the difference of two dates in Hours or seconds, then just change the `timeUnit` to `TimeUnit.SECONDS` or `TimeUnit.HOURS`

```
    TimeUnit timeUnit = TimeUnit.DAYS;

    String dateTime_form_api = "2020/02/11 10:23 AM";

    String dateTime_from_system = "2020/02/11 13:00 PM";

    Date date1, date2;  
    try {
        date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm aa").parse(dateTime_from_system);
        date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm aa").parse(dateTime_form_api);

        long diffInMillies = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();

        long diffInDays = timeUnit.convert(diffInMillies, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);  
        System.out.println(diffInDays);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).