# how to check if one date is after another in java?

Tags: java, date, command-line-arguments

I am taking in two dates as command line arguments and want to check if the first one is after the second date. the format of the date it "dd/MM/yyy".
Example: java dateCheck 01/01/2014 15/03/2014
also i will need to check if a third date hardcoded into the program is before the second date.

Comment: Do you have any code to show your attempts so far?

Comment: The javadoc for `Date` would have shown you that 1. it implements `Comparable` and 2. it has `.before()` and `.after()` methods

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare dates in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/compare-dates-in-java)

Comment: Did you mean to use four “y” characters? So, "dd/MM/yyyy" instead of "dd/MM/yyy"?

Answer (score 4):

To compare two dates :

```
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy");

            Date firstDate = sdf.parse("01/01/2014");
            Date secondDate = sdf.parse("15/03/2014");

            if(firstDate.before(secondDate)){
                System.out.println("firstDate <  secondDate");
            }
            else if(firstDate.after(secondDate)){
                System.out.println("firstDate >  secondDate");
            }
            else if(firstDate.equals(secondDate)){
                System.out.println("firstDate = secondDate");
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
try {
    System.out.println("Enter first date : (dd/MM/yyyy)");
    BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date1 = sdf.parse(bufferRead.readLine());
    System.out.println("Enter second date : (dd/MM/yyyy)");
    Date date2 = sdf.parse(bufferRead.readLine());
    System.out.println(date1 + "\n" + date2);
    if (date1.after(date2)) {
        System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");
    } else {
            System.out.println("Date2 is after Date1");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use SimpleDateFormat to convert a string to Date.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date1 = sdf.parse("01/01/2017");
```

[Date](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) has [before](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)) and [after](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)) methods and can be [compared to each other](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)) as follows:

```
if(todayDate.after(historyDate) && todayDate.before(futureDate)) {
    // In between
}
```

For an inclusive comparison:

```
if(!historyDate.after(todayDate) && !futureDate.before(todayDate)) {
    /* historyDate <= todayDate <= futureDate */ 
}
```

Comment: (a) Your formatting pattern does not suit your example data. Three 'y' characters instead of four, and a SLASH instead of a FULL STOP. (b) FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate ld1 = LocalDate.parse( "01/01/2014" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ) ;
LocalDate ld2 = LocalDate.parse( "15/03/2014" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ) ;
LocalDate ld3 = LocalDate.of( 2014 , Month.JULY , 1 ) ;

Boolean isFirstDateBeforeSecondDate = ld1.isBefore( ld2 ) ;
Boolean isThirdDateBeforeSecondDate = ld3.isBefore( ld2 ) ;

Boolean result = ( isFirstDateBeforeSecondDate && isThirdDateBeforeSecondDate ) ;

return result ;
```

## Using java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes rather than the troublesome old legacy date-time classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, etc.).

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Define a formatting pattern to match your input strings using the `DateTimeFormatter` class.

```
String input = "15/03/2014" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
```

> ld.toString(): 2014-03-15

To specify a fixed date, pass *year*, *month*, and *dayOfMonth*. For the month, you may specify a number, sanely numbered 1-12 for January-December (unlike the crazy 0-11 in the legacy classes!). Or you may choose to use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects.

```
LocalDate firstOf2014 = LocalDate.of( 2014 , Month.JANUARY , 1 );
```

Compare using `isBefore`, `isEqual`, or `isAfter` methods.

```
Boolean isInputDateBeforeFixedDate = ld.isBefore( firstOf2014 ) ;
```

> isInputDateBeforeFixedDate.toString(): false

## ISO 8601

If possible, replace your particular date string format with the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. That standard defines many useful practical unambiguous string formats for date-time values.

The java.time classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. You can see examples in the code above. For a date-only value, the standard format is YYYY-MM-DD.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

To read a date and check before:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy");
try {
    Date date1 = sdf.parse(string1);
    Date date2 = sdf.parse(string2);
    if(date1.before(date2)) {
       // do something
    }
} catch(ParseException e) {
    // the format of the read dates is not the expected one
}
```