# compare two time values in java

Tags: android

I want to get the current system time and compare with the two different timing example start time as 2:00:00AM and end as 6:00:00AM. if my current system time falls between these  i have to execute my rest of the code and show the output in textview.
 i have this use this code for getting the current time i need help for using start and end time in if condition.

```
enter code here



 TextView tvTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 

    if (if (c.getTime() == 2:00:00 AM && < 6:00:00 AM) {

   tvTime.setText(" " + timeFormat.format(c.getTime()));
   }
```

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/compare-dates-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `before()` and `after()` methods of `Calender`

```
public boolean isTimeWithinInterval(String lwrLimit, String uprLimit, String time){

    // Time 1 in string - Lower limit
    Date time_1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(lwrLimit);
    Calendar calendar_1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar_1.setTime(time_1);

    // Time 2 in string - Upper limit
    Date time_2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(uprLimit);
    Calendar calendar_2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar_2.setTime(time_2);

    // Time 3 in String - to be checked
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(time);
    Calendar calendar_3 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar_3.setTime(d);

    Date x = calendar_3.getTime();
    if (x.after(calendar_1.getTime()) && x.before(calendar_2.getTime())) {
        //checkes whether the current time is between two times
        Log.d(TAG,true+"");
        return true;
    } 

    return false;
}
```

Update :

```
 boolean timeChk = isTimeWithinInterval(time1, time2, time3);

 if(timeChk){
   // Success code
   tvTime.setText(" " + time3);
 }
 else{
   // Failure code

 }
```

Comment: thanks  ritesh please tell me how to print the output in textview, im new to java.

Comment: thankss but where to add these updated lines im getting error on log.d and tag.

Comment: you can remove that line, that was put just to explain.

Comment: time1 is for 2am, and time2 is for 6am say, time is the one you want to check. I am giving general solution.

Comment: If it's working for you, then plz mark it as answer so that future users would benefit from it.

Comment: but it is not parsing  in correct format. its giving me output in this way Thu Jun 04 04:36:00 GMT+05:00 1970.

Comment: you can use any valid format you want, what i gave was just an example.

Comment: i am having problem in parsing the strings, using any other format does not support the after and before methods of calendar. can you suggest something.

Comment: Ritesh plz can u tell me how to add a countdown timer in this code to calculate the time left for the interval.

Comment: Let us keep this thread clean.Plz ask this question in new thread giving reference to this question.I will reply there.

Comment: thanks Ritesh plz check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465379/android-eclipse-how-to-set-a-count-down-timer-in-android/23465456?noredirect=1#23465456

Comment: Ritesh I have asked this question in the new thread and this is the link                           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465379/android-eclipse-how-to-set-a-count-down-timer-in-android/23465456?noredirect=1#23465456

Comment: As your question there is on hold, I can not answer that. Plz put the question properly, or delete that post and ask again properly in new thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should really try to use `Calendar` class that is WAY easier and that has that feature with [Calendar.before(calendar)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#before%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, java have problem with Date and Time.

You should use **Joda Time** It's date and time library to replace JDK date handling

Download: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time/2.3