# Why the notification do not appear?

Tags: android, date, android-sqlite, android-notifications

I have an android application that use SQLite database to store data. One of its field is **match_date** that contain the date with time.

What I want is to create notification that include the team names and the date after comparing the current date with the stored date in the database and if they match a notification must appear.

The application work perfectly but without getting any notification so where is my error an how to fix this error?

I will appreciate any help.

**This is my database table**:

```
CREATE TABLE [match_list] (
  [_id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  [stad_name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  [team1] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  [team2] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  [stage] varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
  [match_date] DATETIME NOT NULL, 
  [flags1] CHAR(255), 
  [flags2] CHAR(255), 
  [group_team] CHAR(1));
```

**FirstActivity.java**:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txtDate;

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private ExternalDbOpenHelper extDB;

    private static final String DB_NAME = "world_cup.db";
    // *****Tables name**************************//
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "match_list";

    // *****Tbale name******************************

    public static final String PLACE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String STAD_NAME = "stad_name";
    public static final String TEAM1 = "team1";
    public static final String TEAM2 = "team2";
    public static final String MATCH_DATE = "match_date";
    public static final String FLAG1 = "flags1";
    public static final String FLAG2 = "flags2";

    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] { PLACE_ID, STAD_NAME,
            TEAM1, TEAM2, MATCH_DATE, FLAG1, FLAG2, };
    // *****Tbale name******************************

    ItemDetails listdetail;

    Cursor c;

    private static final int myNotificationId = 1;


    ///////////////////////
    long diffSeconds;
    long diffMinutes;
    long diffHours;
    long diffDays;
    ///////////////////////

    //for the alarm amanager and the notification
    public static int eventID = 1;

    Date d1 = new Date();

    SimpleDateFormat format;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    // private DatabaseHelper dbHelper = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        getDiffDate();

        extDB = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
        database = extDB.openDataBase();

        showNotification();

         Log.e("inside the onCreate", "inside onCreate");


    }


    public void listTeams(View v) {
        Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    public void listGroups(View v) {
        Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), GroupList.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    public void DisplaySched(View v) {

        Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MatchScheduleList.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
        return true;
    }


      public void getDiffDate() {

        String dateStop = "06/12/2014 23:00:00";

        // HH converts hour in 24 hours format (0-23), day calculation
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        d1 = new Date();


        Date d2 = null;

        try {

            d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

            // in milliseconds
            long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

            long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
            long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
            long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
            long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

            System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
            System.out.print(diffHours + " hours, ");
            System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
            System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds.");

            txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDifDate);
            String resultDate = diffDays + "days " + diffHours + "Hours "
                    + diffMinutes + "Min " + diffSeconds + "S";
            txtDate.setText(resultDate);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public Cursor getAllRows(PendingIntent notificationIntent) {
        String where = null;

        c = database.query(true, TABLE_NAME, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        if (c != null) {

            c.moveToFirst();


            while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
                listdetail = new ItemDetails();

                listdetail.setTeam1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("team1")));

                listdetail.setTeam2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("team2")));

                listdetail.setDate_match(c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex("match_date")));




                 // if the pick up date from the database is equal to the current date the notification will pop up 

                long i = (int) (new Date().getTime()/1000);

                 //// from the internet 
                 int index = c.getColumnIndex("match_date");
                 long time = c.getLong(index);
                 ////////
                 Log.e("inside the Shownotification", "index is" + index);


                if(time == i){

                     Log.e("inside the Shownotification", "time is" + time);

                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new Builder(
                            getApplicationContext());
                    Notification notification = builder
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fifa_2014_4)
                            .setContentTitle("Up Comming Match")
                            .setContentText(
                                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("match_date"))
                                            + (c.getColumnIndex("team1"))
                                            + (c.getColumnIndex("team2"))).build();


                    displayNotification(notification);
            }

                c.moveToNext();
        }

      }
        return c;
    }

    // for the notification

    private PendingIntent preparePendingIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

         Log.e("inside the preparePendingIntent", "inside preparePendingIntent");

        return pendingIntent;

    }

    private void showNotification() {



        PendingIntent notificationIntent = preparePendingIntent();
        getAllRows(notificationIntent);

        c.moveToFirst();




    }

    private void displayNotification(Notification notification) {
        Log.e("inside the displayNotification", "inside displayNotification");


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(myNotificationId, notification);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please strip your code to show only the relevant part.

Comment: are you the same person who posted this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441285/how-to-create-android-notification-using-sqlite-database?rq=1 ?

Comment: @NiekHaarman I definitely see your point, but if OP knew which was the relevant part, he/she/it likely wouldn't need to ask this kind of question here. (i.e. what's off/what's missing)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are comparing dates is wrong.

Log out the values of `i` and `time` just before you compare them - I think they will not be equal.

Rather have a look at this question, which shows better ways to compare dates in java:

- [How to compare dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/compare-dates-in-java)

---

Why is the way of comparing wrong?

1. Firstly you are now comparing down to the millisecond level
2. Secondly you are losing information by casting to `(int)`

---

A good way to try and track down an issue like this is to first make a `Notification` from outside any `if..then` blocks, using static data. Once you can do that, then you know that your `Notification` skills are fine.

You would then be able to find out if the Notification stuff is wrong, or the DB stuff.