# Compare two dates with time whose Formate is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss in Android

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I have to compare two dates whose format is **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**. I know the way to compare date only the before or after date function.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
String expiryTime = "2014-09-10 00:00:00";
```

But what's the best way to compare date and time with the current date and time. 
Like we have two dates 2014-09-10 00:00:00 and current date with time is 2014-08-31 10:37:15. And now we have to compare it. How we can do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: create Date objects from these Strings.  See SimpleDateForm class

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare dates in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the Date String to `java.util.Date` object using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and compare those date objects with [`Date#after`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)) or [`Date#before`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)) methods.

---

In **java 8** - using new [Java Time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), parse date String using  `DateTimeFormat` and get `LocalDate` object and compare them.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
final LocalDate dt1 = dtf.parseLocalDate(dateString1);
final LocalDate dt2 = dtf.parseLocalDate(dateString2);

final boolean check = dt1.isAfter(dt2);
if(check)
    System.out.println(dt1 +" is after "+dt2);
else
    System.out.println(dt2 +" is after "+dt1);
```

Comment: You seem to be missing open `"` for your String literals in the `System.out.println()` calls.

Comment: In place of DateTimeFormatter I have used SimpleDateFormat in Android.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand what you're trying to do you want to use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (and you posted a good pattern) to parse the `String`(s) into `Date`(s) and then [`Date.before(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29). Putting that together into something like,

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String firstStr = "2014-09-10 00:00:00";
String secondStr = "2014-08-31 10:37:15";
Date first = sdf.parse(firstStr);
Date second = sdf.parse(secondStr);
boolean before = (first.before(second));
System.out.printf("%s is before %s",
    before ? firstStr : secondStr,
    before ? secondStr : firstStr);
```

Output is

```
2014-08-31 10:37:15 is before 2014-09-10 00:00:00
```

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder The ternary is part of the language. But you could always implement it as a simple `if else` if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

```
try{

      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    } catch (ParseException e1) 
      {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

       String str1 = "2014-09-10 00:00:00";
       Date date1 = formatter.parse(str1);

        String str2 = "2014-08-31 10:37:15";
       Date date2 = formatter.parse(str2);

    if (date1.compareTo(date2)<0)
    {
    System.out.println("date2 is Greater than my date1");                          
    }
```