# How to compare and find dates in a database?

Tags: android, sqlite, date-comparison

My Android app contains a table consisting of birthdays of friends. How can I get the dates within a given range? How will I compare dates?

Comment: Well, you could start by reading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html).

Comment: What date format are you using in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object and use the [before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29) and [after](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29) methods. For more, see [How to compare dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can compare dates using `java.util.Date#compareTo`.