# How to set a minimum date to a jFormattedTextField?

Tags: java, swing, date, awt, jformattedtextfield

I'm coding in Java using `Netbeans` IDE.

I want to make a limitation for a `jFormattedTextField.`

There are two `jFormattedTextFields`. One is `Start Date(date1)`. Other is `End Date(date2)`. Now I want to limit the minimum date to the "End Date". If some one types `2015-07-07` as a `Start Date`, it must restrict to give past days `(2015-07-06,05,04 days)`.

Comment: I think JFormattedTextField will not handle this, but check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java) out

Comment: @m.cekiera oh.... Firstly thank you for you reply sir. It is no problem ,if there is a way to do this by a jTextField too.I just used jformattedtextfields as I do not want to code the limitation for the date format. Do you have a method for jTextField sir..?

Comment: 1. see AbstractFormatter, I'm sure that I'm posted here a few times for number, 2. job exactly for JSpinner with SpinnerDateModel :-)

Comment: You want to make the earlier date the end date?  That's backwards from convention.

Answer (score 0):

use [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) to add validation:

```
final JFormattedTextField startDateField = ...;
JFormattedTextField endDateField = ...;

((AbstractDocument)endDateField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter(){
    @Override
    public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException{
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder(fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength()));
        content.replace(offset, offset + length, "");
        if(isValidEndDate(content.toString()))
            super.remove(fb, offset, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException{
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder(fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength()));
        content.insert(offset, string);
        if(isValidEndDate(content.toString()))
            super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException{
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder(fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength()));
        content.replace(offset, offset + length, text);
        if(isValidEndDate(content.toString()))
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
    }

    boolean isValidEndDate(String endDate){
        //check whether endDate is <= startDateField.getText()
    }
});
```