# Months difference using java, to navigate to next or previous page

Tags: java, date, selenium

I've to write a generic code as such, it should give months difference between two dates.

For eg., my input data will be

```
1.  date1 = 22/01/2016
date2 = 30/03/2016
2. date1 = 22/01/2016
date2 = 20/12/2015
```

based on months difference, I've to move **forward(if date2 is future date to date1)** or **backward(if date2 is past date to date1)**, those many times.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Is 'date1' a string?

Comment: Not string, it is in date format only. Like,
Date date = new Date(22,01,2016);

Comment: What do you mean by moving forward and backward? In wabpages? If yes, are you using Java servlets?

Comment: In a java page, based on difference, i have to click on links to next or previous pages.(no: of clicks is the no: of months differ in between date and date2)

Comment: @MadhaviMokkapati I would advise you to add more tags to your question and explicitly state your question clearly. If not, I fear you probably can't get much help here.....

Comment: @user3437460, Actually no other tags to add, just a simple java page.

If **date2 is future date to date1**, then I've to give clicks on **next button**.

If **date2 is past date to date1**, then I've to give clicks on **previous button**.

Clicks = no:of months difference

Answer (score 0):

You could simply compare these two dates as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java)

According to the result you just have to call the same code as if you have clicked on the button yourself (just call the respective mehtod (if you don't use a method for that I would advise you to do so))

Greetings Raven

**EDIT:**
The difference betweent two dates can be calculated [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Comment: actually, i want no: of months to give clicks using selenium-click

Comment: so you need the difference between the two dates?

Comment: only months difference. and dates combination can be : [date1(present),date2(future)] or [date1(present), date2(past)]

Comment: [date1(present),date2(future)] - with this difference i have to click on next. And, [date1(present), date2(past)] - with this difference i have to click on previous. But the bad thing is, I cant predict date2 whether it is 'Future' or 'Past'.

Comment: Then just subtract the different month values and multiply by -1 if necessary... Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you missed to see my previous comment. Once check with that.

Comment: Thank so much for help. But, if simple subtraction is performed, then how to make clicks on diff buttons like next and previous.

Comment: Well if the difference is greater zero then the second date is in the past (assuming that you substract month1 by month2) and if it is less zero then vise versa...And the modulus gives you the amount of clicks you have to perform on the respective button

Comment: Thanq u so much, for help

Comment: Assuming Month1-Month2, for getting months difference,
if years are same and If month1= 03 and month2 = 01, then it is 2 and ans is fyn
but if years are different and if month1 = 12 and month2 = 03, then it is 9 and ans is not fyn

Comment: You have to calculate the difference between 12-difference and the difference itself

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar data2 = Calendar.getInstance();
int diff =(int) Math.round(( (data2.getTimeInMillis() - data.getTimeInMillis()) /* ms*/
              / 1000.0 /* seconds*/
              / 3600.0 /*hours*/
              / 24.0 /*days*/
              / 30.0 ))/* monts*/;
```

With Math.round you ensure months of 31 and 28 days return the right value
Replace data and data2 for your own values

Comment: Thanks for help. But, it gives days differences, i require months difference

Comment: No, it gives months differences. Check it out

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Period.between( 
    LocalDate.of( 2016 , Month.JANUARY , 22 ) , 
    LocalDate.of( 2016 , Month.MARCH , 30 )
).isNegative()
```

## Details

Your Question is not clear, but this might help point you in the right direction.

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes such as `Date` that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

date1 = 22/01/2016
date2 = 30/03/2016

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2016 , Month.JANUARY , 22 ) ;
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2016 , Month.MARCH , 30 ) ;
```

### `Period`

Calculate the number of days, months, and years elapsed as a `Period`.

```
Period period = Period.between( start , stop ) ;
```

Test if the stop comes before the start, meaning the elapsed time is negative, going backwards along the timeline.

```
Boolean isTimeGoingBackwards = period.isNegative() ;
```

### Months

Your comments mention getting a number of months. Understand multiple ways to count months:

- Count days elapsed, divided by 30 as the length of a generic month.
- Count of calendar months completely covered
- Count of calendar months touched by the span of time

Java offers at least some of these. Read the documentation to decide which meets your needs. If going backwards in time, the resulting number is negative.

#### `ChronoUnit.MONTHS`

```
long months = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between( start , stop ) ;
```

#### `Period.toTotalMonths`

```
int months = Period.between( start , stop ).toTotalMonths() ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).