# Compare the time

Tags: java

I have following 2 time stamps,

```
Wed, 24 Feb 2016 09:02:12
Tue, 23 Feb 2016 09:01:59
```

how to compare them,

I am aware about we have inbuilt method for comparing date but do we have something for the given scenario.

Edit: Here i thought to compare the time first for example 09:02:12 and 09:01:59, which i can achieve by calculating hour , minutes and seconds into a single unit and can check which one is greater , but this will work fine if the date is same , my logic will not work if the date is different.

I have refereed this question as well

[How to compare dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java)

but I am still not sure that this will be helpfull for my scenario.

Comment: Do you want a `boolean` as a result?

Comment: Yes, I want to check the 1st is greater than the 2nd one. I can think of comparing the time by calculating it into seconds, but not able to get the logic when it comes with date.

Comment: You need to provide more information.

Comment: You know that there are calendar clases in Java?

Comment: Will the time be taken into consideration ?

Comment: Look up how to parse a Date String with SimpleDateFormat, then you can compare whatever timestamps you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String date1Str = "Wed, 24 Feb 2016 09:02:12";
        String date2Str = "Tue, 23 Feb 2016 09:01:59";

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss"); //Create formatter based on your required formats

        try
        {
            Date date1 = format.parse(date1Str); //convert string to date object
            Date date2 = format.parse(date2Str);
            System.out.println(date1.after(date2)); //compare the date
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

for different formats https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html