# Calculating date in mysql with java

Tags: java, mysql, date

I'm having trouble, finding out how to calculate or get the date from mysql (using java program) after 1 month of the initial saved date given below:

```
Date rDate = new Date();
java.sql.Date regDate = new java.sql.Date(rDate.getTime());
```

I am saving the date into a date column in mysql and I want to have another column which contains the date but one month ahead. In other words I have a registration date and I want to have an expiration date calculated automatically which allows only 1 month. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grabbing the current date and set it into the Calendar format and add 1 to the month.

You can give this a try.

```
Date rDate = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(rDate);
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alvin. Had no idea it was that easy.

Comment: No problem! Accept this as correct answer if it's working by clicking the tick.

Comment: There's many answers posted for such qns, here's one [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java)

Comment: Yeah, I later realized and deleted my comment but thank you

Comment: No problem, always glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Calendar` class to manipulate date fields:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
Date futureDate = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Thank you @ujulu. I had searched a lot for the answer. Guessed I should have just read up on the Calendar class.