# How to compare user selected date with from and to date in Android?

Tags: java, android, date-comparison, date

I want to compare user selected date with from date and to date.
e.g.,

```
from date : 2017-25-07
to date   : 2017-31-07
Selected date : 2017-27-07
```

so now I want to check selected date is in the range between from date and to date.

Comment: Googling your problem statement is the first thing that you should do.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically the first section, *Search, and research*. What did your search and research bring up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can compare three dates by below code

```
if(!fromDate.after(selectedDate) && !toDate.before(selectedDate)) {
  //fromDate <= selectedDate <= toDate
}
```

Comment: yes it is working
Thank you

Comment: Since a `java.util.Date` holds both a date and a time-of-day, some tricky surprises may come out when the date it the same and the time-of-day is different. It will be easier and a lot less errorprone with `LocalDate`. To use it on Android, you need the ThreeTenABP, see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).