# Any ideas on how I could compare 2 dates in string format?

Tags: java, selenium, datetime, datetime-parsing, datetime-comparison

Any ideas on how I could compare 2 dates in string format:

```
String1 = "Wed May 18 00:00:00 CDT 2011"
String2= "May. 18, 2011"
```

I tried converting `String1` to date format of `String2` but was not very successful.

I tried converting `String1` to date using pattern `"EEE mmm dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"`

```
public String formatDateTime(Date date, String pattern) {  
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);  
    String dateString = formatter.format(date);  
    return dateString;  
}
```

Comment: Use `DateFormat`s (or Java 8's `DateTimeFormatter`), convert to machine objects and compare those.

Comment: Duplicate: [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4216745/642706) & [How to compare dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2592501/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will work, however, you do need to be mindful of the timezone that the computer is running on. The second date does not have a timezone will cause problems if the second date was generated in say EDT.

```
String d1 = "Wed May 18 00:00:00 CDT 2011";
String d2 = "May. 18, 2011";

SimpleDateFormat d1Formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat d2Formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM. dd, yyyy");

Date date1 = d1Formatter.parse(d1);
Date date2 = d2Formatter.parse(d2);

date1.equals(date2);
```

Note all of the patterns that I used came from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). I would suggest creating a unit test and testing what different combinations do.

```
@Test
public void test_date_experimentation() {
    SimpleDateFormat d1Formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");

    // Print the current time in the specified format.
    System.out.println(d1Formatter.format(Date.from(Instant.now())));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert a `String` to a `Date`, you should use the `parse` method. But you're using the `format` method, which does the opposite (it converts a `Date` to a `String`).

To check if the 2 `String`'s correspond to the same date, you must parse them with a `SimpleDateFormat` for each one. But there are 2 details to keep in mind:

- Note that the month and day of week are in English, so you should use a `java.util.Locale` to indicate what language you want to use. If you don't specify one, it'll use the system's default, and it's not guaranteed to always be English.

  Even if it is, this configuration can be changed without notice, even at runtime, so it's always better to explicity use a specific one.
- The first `String` has timezone information: `CDT` - which I'm assuming it's **Central Daylight Time** of USA (although [it could also be Cuba Daylight Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations)). But the second `String` doesn't have any timezone information, so I'm assuming it'll be in the same timezone as the first `String`.

  If I don't specify it, the system's default will be used and it might give you different results if it's not CDT. And similar to what happen to locales, the default can be changed without notice, even at runtime, so it's better to specify which one you're using.

```java
String s1 = "Wed May 18 00:00:00 CDT 2011";
String s2 = "May. 18, 2011";
// use English locale for month and day of week
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM. dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
// set timezone, because String 2 has no timezone information
sdf2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));

// parse the dates
Date date1 = sdf1.parse(s1);
Date date2 = sdf2.parse(s2);
// compare them
boolean areDatesEqual = date1.equals(date2);
```

The value of variable `areDatesEqual` will be `true` (dates are the same).

Note that I used `America/Chicago` as timezone name. If I used `CDT`, the `TimeZone` class doesn't recognize it and it gives incorrect results.

It's always better to use [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Chicago` or `Europe/London`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CDT` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

There is [more than one timezone that uses CDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone), so you must choose the one that fits best to your system.
You can get a list of available timezones by calling `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`.

---

## Java new Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

As you are comparing just the date (day/month/year), it's better to just work with those fields and ignore the rest (hour/minute/second and timezone information). For that, you can use a `LocalDate` and a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
String s1 = "Wed May 18 00:00:00 CDT 2011";
String s2 = "May. 18, 2011";
// use English locale for month and day of week
DateTimeFormatter fmt1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM. dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
// parse the strings
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.parse(s1, fmt1);
LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.parse(s2, fmt2);
// compare the dates
boolean areDatesEqual = d1.equals(d2);
```

As the `LocalDate` has only day, hour and minute (no hours/minutes/seconds and no timezone information), you don't need to care about setting timezones in the formatters - although the concern on the English locale remains.

The result will also be `true`.