# Java/Webdriver - Comparing date specified in the string with today's date

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I would like to verify that date which appears in the string matches todays date.

For examples:
1. Navigate to Page
2. Get displayed string text "Data Current as of 2017-10-17"
3. Assert to today's date for pass/fail

Comment: Excellent.  Which part is causing you difficulty?

Comment: i need to retrieve the date from text as a date and compare to current date in the system. The format should be ("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: Are you aware of the [DateTimeFormatter class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and have you tried using it?

Comment: I will try, however if you can write the method i would appreciate...

Comment: Well, why don't you give it a try, then post back if you run into a specific problem?

Comment: Ok, sounds good, thanks

Comment: You might end up using the `now()` method of the `LocalDate` class at some point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

`WebElement dateText =
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'Data Current as of')]"));

```
    String fullDateString = dateText.getText();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    String patternString = "(\\d+-\\d+-\\d+)";//use of Reg Ex

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dateText.getText());

    Date repodate = new Date();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        repodate = df.parse(matcher.group());
    }

    Date currDate = df.parse(df.format(new Date()));

    if (currDate == repodate) ///verifing
        ;
    {
        System.out.println(currDate);
        System.out.println(repodate);
    }

    Assert.assertEquals(repodate, currDate);//asserting`
```

Comment: let me know if you any of you would have done it differently, please!