# Java how to do Calendar comparison

Tags: java, date

I am taking start date from one text and storing in one string variable. I want to compare that start date with the current date i.e start date is earlier than the current date or not.

```
public static void main(String[] rags) throws ParseException{
    String total= "I am Going to join in scholl at 21/10/2108";
    String[] effectiveDateText=total.split(" ");
    String effectiveDate=effectiveDateText[effectiveDateText.length-1];
    System.out.println(effectiveDate);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    String todate=sdf.format(today.getTime());
    System.out.println(todate);
    if(effectiveDate<todate){
        System.out.println("effective date is less then the previous date");
    }
```

Comment: Parse them into java.util.Date. Then use .compareTo().

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/calendar_before.htm https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/date_before.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Selenium.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: I may be repeating what I and @BasilBourque have already said, but I find it important enough: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also despite their names neither `Date` nor `Calendar` represents a calendar date.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Use modern [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate.parse(                                       // Represent a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone in `java.time.LocalDate` class.
        "I am Going to join in scholl at 21/10/2108".  // Split your input string, looking for last part separated by a SPACE.
        .substring( 
                "I am Going to join in scholl at 21/10/2108".lastIndexOf( " " ) 
                + 1                 
        ) 
        ,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" )    // Specify formatting pattern to match your input. Tip: Use ISO 8601 formats instead.
)
.toString()                                            // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2108-10-21

## Splitting string

First split the string into pieces.

```
String input = "I am Going to join in scholl at 21/10/2108";
String[] parts = input.split( " " );
```

Look at those parts.

```
for ( String part : parts ) {
    System.out.println( part );
}
```

> I
>
> am
>
> Going
>
> to
>
> join
>
> in
>
> scholl
>
> at
>
> 21/10/2108

Extract the last part.

```
String part = parts[ parts.length - 1 ]; // Subtract 1 for index (annoying zero-based counting).
```

## `LocalDate`

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes. Specifically, `LocalDate` for a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Parse that last part as a `LocalDate`. Define a formatting pattern to match.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( part , f );
```

## ISO 8601

Whenever possible, do not exchange date-time values textually using formats intended for presentation to humans.

Instead, use formats defined for the purpose of data-interchange in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. For a date-only value, that would be: YYYY-MM-DD

The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text.

```
String output = LocalDate.now().toString()
```

> 2018-01-23

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: i up voted, concepts explained well and complications reduced

Answer (score 0):

You shoud parse your dates into the Date format and the use the provided methods like this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Date date1 = sdf.parse("21/10/2108");
    Date date2 = sdf.parse("20/01/2018");

    System.out.println("date1 : " + sdf.format(date1));
    System.out.println("date2 : " + sdf.format(date2));

    // after
    if (date1.after(date2)) {

    }
    // before
    if (date1.before(date2)) {

    }
```

**nice to know:**
You should be carefull if you what to use date1.equals(date2) since this works on milliseconds precision aswell so you have to use a date delta if you allow user to enter time values in the future.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

A Java [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) has very useful methods to compare two instant with each other, namely [`isAfter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#isAfter-java.time.Instant-) and [`isBefore()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#isBefore-java.time.Instant-). See this example:

```
String total = "I am Going to join in scholl at 21/10/2018";
String[] effectiveDateText = total.split(" ");
String effectiveDate = effectiveDateText[effectiveDateText.length - 1];
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Instant joinDate = sdf.parse(effectiveDate).toInstant();
if (Instant.now().isAfter(joinDate)) {
    // ...
}
```

You should however consider timezones. For instance, at present time (`Instant.now()`), at most parts in the world, it's 12/10/2018, at some however, it's already 13/10/2018 (Samoa), and at others it's 11/10/2018 (the US Minor Outlying Islands, only one minute left).

BTW, I changed 21/10/2108 to 21/10/2018.

Comment: `Instant` is not the right class here. The problem involves a date-only value (no time-of-day, no time zone), but `Instant` is a moment, a date with time-of-day in UTC. So not properly representative. Instead, use `LocalDate`.

Comment: Also when you can use java.time — which is a very good idea — mixing the outdated and troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends in is just overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for comparison,

```
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDateTime.now().toLocalDate();
String cDate = ""+currentTime.getMonth().toString()+"/"+currentTime.getDayOfMonth().toString()+"/"+currentTime.getYear().toString();
```

Now cDate will have date string in format of dd/MM/yyyy.
So for comaparison you can use Date class,

```
Date dOne = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(cDate);
Date dTwo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(effectiveDate);
```

then use compareTo() method on both the dates,

```
dOne.compareTo(dTwo); // check value of this method
```

This return 0 if both dates are same,
if less than 0 means Date is before the argument date,
if greater than 0 means Date is after the argument date.

Comment: Why are you mixing the modern *java.time* classes with the terrible legacy classes? As of JSR 310, the legacy classes are entirely supplanted, and need not ever be used at all.

Comment: @BasilBourque is right, this is really overcomplicating things.