# I want to compare my current mobile date with my firebase date and then show data on which date user click

Tags: java

I want to compare current date with my firebase date and then show data on which the user clicks and show specific date data I am new in android and I don't know how to do this.
I need help...
I tried many solution but doesn't solve my problem.
I tried something like this...

```java
imageRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("NamazTime");

        imageRef.child("April").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        String name = snapshot.getKey();
                        Log.d("Value", snapshot.getKey());
                        Abname.add(name);

                        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
              (getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_text_color, Abname);
                        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_text_color);
                        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
 loadingBar.dismiss();

                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                loadingBar.dismiss();

            }
        });


spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                        .child("NamazTime").child("April").child(selectedItem);

                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                            dbfajar = dataSnapshot.child("FAJR1").getValue().toString();
                            fajartime.setText(dbfajar);
                            dbasar = dataSnapshot.child("ASR1").getValue().toString();
                            asartime.setText(dbasar);
                            dbmaghrib = dataSnapshot.child("MAGHRIB1").getValue().toString();
                            maghribtime.setText(dbmaghrib);
                            dbesha = dataSnapshot.child("ISHA1").getValue().toString();
                            eshatime.setText(dbesha);
                            dbzohar = dataSnapshot.child("ZUHR1").getValue().toString();
                            zohartime.setText(dbzohar);
                            String sehertime1 = "-";
                            seherTime.setText(sehertime1);
                            String iftartime1 = "-";
                            iftartime.setText(iftartime1);

                            dbjamatfajar = dataSnapshot.child("FAJR2").getValue().toString();
                            fajarjamattime.setText(dbjamatfajar);
                            dbjamatasar = dataSnapshot.child("ASR2").getValue().toString();
                            asarjamattime.setText(dbjamatasar);
                            maghribjamattim = findViewById(R.id.dbmaghribjamattim);
                            dbiftar = dataSnapshot.child("MAGHRIB2").getValue().toString();
                            if (dbiftar.length() > 0) {
                                maghribjamattim.setText(dbiftar);
                            }
                            dbjamatesha = dataSnapshot.child("ISHA2").getValue().toString();
                            eshajamattime.setText(dbjamatesha);
                            dbjamatzohar = dataSnapshot.child("ZUHR2").getValue().toString();
                            zoharjamattime.setText(dbjamatzohar);
                            String sehertime = "-";
                            seherjamattime.setText(sehertime);
                            String iftartime = "-";
                            iftarjamattime.setText(iftartime);

                            loadingBar.dismiss();

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java

Comment: you may want to edit this question to remove all superfluous code and leave exclusively what's needed to replicate the issue you're having.

Comment: i am using firebase and in firebase i have a node in which prayer time is define the problem is that i want to compare my current date with firebase date using query and then show firebase date data in my text view.....