# fromdate less than todate datepicker

Tags: java, android

I have a project where in two buttons are there named from and todate.And I need to show the status of the project based on start and end Date after pressing the button refresh.The problem is that I want to get the selected date when I press from date and when I press toDate it allow user to select the date and from date should always be less than the todate

```
public void showDatePicker(final Button view1) {
    // Get Current Date
       final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
       mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
       mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


       if (view1.getId() == R.id.to_date) {
          if (fromDateData == null ||   "startfrom".equalsIgnoreCase(fromDateData) || fromDateData.isEmpty())
            return;
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String[] dates = fromDateData.split("-");
        mYear = Integer.parseInt(dates[2]);
        mMonth = Integer.parseInt(dates[1]) - 1;
        mDay = Integer.parseInt(dates[0]);
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
    }




      if (view1.getId() == R.id.to_date) {
            if (fromDateData == null || "start         from".equalsIgnoreCase(fromDateData) || fromDateData.isEmpty())
                return;
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            String[] dates = fromDateData.split("-");
            mYear = Integer.parseInt(dates[2]);
            mMonth = Integer.parseInt(dates[1]) - 1;
            mDay = Integer.parseInt(dates[0]);
            c.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
            c.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
        }                  

   if (view1.getId() == R.id.from_date)
   fromDateData=date;
   else
   toDateData = date;
    view1.setText(date);
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
     if (view1.getId() != R.id.from_date)
                                                                                                                                                    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());

          datePickerDialog.show();
   }
```

Comment: please help me to fix this issue

Comment: you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java

Comment: Please edit and write question, description and code properly here!

Comment: No I didn't get

Comment: @Nick Bapu-Sorry for the mistake and by the way Im new to android

Comment: I need to preserve the selected date if I either pressed the start or end date and (from date)start date should always be lesser than the end date(todate)

Comment: ANYBODY knowing the solution please help me