# When using .compareTo to compare dates, why doesn't it take Months into account?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting, compareto

I'm displaying certain dates from an ArrayList and using a formatter to shorten the date to "dd/MM" but when I compare the dates it doesn't work for the months. e.g. 17/08 IS before 19/08, 21/08 IS after 19/08 but 17/09 IS before 19/08. What my program achieves is showing any of the dates within the next 8 days.

I've tried using .compareTo to do this and it works within a month but not going between months. I know it's comparing strings and I think that's the problem but I don't know how to get around it

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date comDate = new Date();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 8);
//this adds days to the calender
comDate = cal.getTime();
String strDate = formatter.format(comDate);
//this applies the edited calender to the date I'm comparing to

ArrayList<String> arDat = new ArrayList<String>();
arDat.add("15/08");
arDat.add("15/09");
arDat.add("30/08");

Date recDate = new Date();

for (int i=0; i < arDat.size(); i++){
    recDate = formatter.parse(arDat(i));
    String strRecDate = formatter.format(recDate);
    if (strRecDate.compareTo(strDate) < 0 {
        showToast(recDate);
    }
}
```

I want it to just show 15/08 but it shows 15/08 and 15/09

Comment: you used new library in java 8 date time api

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

Comment: related Answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `MonthDay` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you format it converts to `String`. You are formatting and comparing. Hence it is doing `String` comparison. Hence, the result.

If you want the expected result, you must compare `Date` objects. I have modified your code to compare both `Strings` and `Dates`.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class CompareDates {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date comDate = new Date();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 8);
        //this adds days to the calender
        comDate = cal.getTime();
        //this applies the edited calender to the date I'm comparing to

        ArrayList<String> arDat = new ArrayList<String>();
        arDat.add("15/08");
        arDat.add("15/09");
        arDat.add("30/08");

        Date redDate = new Date();
        for (int i = 0; i < arDat.size(); i++) {
            Date recDate = formatter.parse(arDat.get(i));
            if (formatter.format(recDate).compareTo(formatter.format(comDate)) < 0) {
                System.out.println("String comparison result: " + recDate);
            }
            if (recDate.compareTo(formatter.parse(formatter.format(comDate))) < 0) {
                System.out.println("Date comparison result: " + recDate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output as expected (only Aug 15 is printed when compared as Date):

```
String comparison result: Sat Aug 15 00:00:00 UTC 1970
Date comparison result: Sat Aug 15 00:00:00 UTC 1970
String comparison result: Tue Sep 15 00:00:00 UTC 1970
```

**Note:** I did not directly compare `recDate` with `compDate` as `compDate` is of the current year (`2019`) and `recDate` is of default year (`1970`). Hence, first I formatted `compDate` to strip off the year, time, etc. and then again parsed to `Date` before comparison.

Comment: The terrible date-time classes used here were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes as of the adoption of JSR 310. Find the modern solution in the [the Answer by michalk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57536487/642706).

Comment: Yes, switching to ` java.time` classes is highly recommended.

Answer (score 3):

## `java.time.MonthDay`

Instead of using outdated `Calendar` class you can use modern `java.time` classes. If you are interested in days and months you can use [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) class and it's compareTo method :

```
MonthDay monthDay = MonthDay.of(8, 15);
MonthDay monthDay1 = MonthDay.of(9, 15);
System.out.println(monthDay.compareTo(monthDay1));
```

gives :

```
-1
```

You might find more convenient the methods [`MonthDay::isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html#isBefore(java.time.MonthDay)), [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html#isAfter(java.time.MonthDay)), and [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

The *java.time* classes are built into Java 8 and later. For Java 6 and Java 7, add the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library to your project.

Comment: I know but I'm limited to a very old java at the moment because I'm using an old work laptop

Comment: @TomPallaghy Then add the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library to your project, where most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7. Well worth the bother, as the legacy really are that bad, terrible, bloody awful bad.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the strings of the date. The Calendar class implements the `Comparable` interface. It will compare correctly.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

So your code in the fixed version:

```
for (int i=0; i < arDat.size(); i++){
    recDate = formatter.parse(arDat(i));
    if (recDate.compareTo(comDate) < 0 {
        showToast(recDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why *does* it work for excluding 30/08 and how do I implement the comparable with the calendar class