# Finding overlapping records at java side

Tags: java, list, algorithm, hashmap

Have a Map as `HashMap<ItemNo, List<Price>>` in my application. Each itemNo having many price intervals.
Each price interval is having FROM_DTIME, TO_DTIME.
Need to find the all price objects whose are having overlapping interval by writing java logic.
Example overlapping interval is as below, 2nd interval should start after completion of 1st interval i.e 01-SEP-19. but it started at 08-AUG-19.

i tried as below ,

```
    for (int i = 0; i < vGroupedByItemNoMap.get(itemNo).size(); i++) {
              Price vCurrent = vGroupedByItemNoMap.get(itemNo).get(i);
              Price vNext = (i == 0 ? null : vGroupedByItemNoMap.get(itemNo).get(i + 1));
DateTime vCurrentTodate = vCurrent.getToDate().plusSeconds(1);
          if (vNext != null) {
            DateTime vNextFromdate = vNext.getFromDate();
            if (vCurrentTodate != vNextFromdate) {
                  vOverlappedItemNoList.addAll(vGroupedByItemNoMap.get(itemNo));

                  log.info(
                      "Prices having Overlapping and [ItemNos ={}] are  not processed.",vOverlappedItemNoList);
                  break;
                }
              }
            }
```

[image]

Can any one help me here how find such overlapping intervals.

Comment: Can you describe what you have tried and show your code?

Comment: I tried as below code,

Comment: Using indexed for loop getting the current iteration and next iteration price objects.compared them as if (vCurrent.getFromDate().plusSeconds(1) != vNext.getToDate()) then these 2 prices having overlapping.

Comment: A couple of pointers which may help you to improve your solution: [How to iterate over a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-java-map); [How to compare two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java).