# How to make an Android App expires after a fixed time period

Tags: java, android, time

I'd like to program an app that, will be avaliable for only a month. I'd like to check when starting the app whether it's over that that given date( 2020 may. 22, but I don't know how to do that. Could somebody tell me how to compare the current time with a preseted date?

Comment: Have look into date comparision https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java OR https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compare-dates-in-java/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your app's `onCreate()` method and change the date. The `doSomething()` method will be called once the date expires.

```
String expiryDateString = "22-May-2020"; // upcoming date
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date expiryDate = formatter.parse(expiryDateString);

if(System.currentTimeMillis() > expiryDate.getTime()){
    // app is expired
    doSomething();
}
```

but please note that this is not a secure method as one can change the system time and date and this test fails. So a better method would be to use flags in the server and check it every time the app starts.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 0):

Make a static variable that contains the current time and check it when the program starts (or in a loop if that's what you require)

```java
public class Main {
    private static final long DATE_STARTED = 1587575414548;

    if(DATE_STARTED + 2592000000 < System.currentTimeInMillis()) { // 2592000000 is 30 days in milliseconds
        // Handle stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off of @JackChap77's comment, if you want to find the current time, use 
    `new Date().getTime()` to retrieve the current time in milliseconds and then store that in a final variable. Make sure to only use it once, though, as you don't want to retrieve the current time each time the program is loaded.