# Date comparision giving false output

Tags: java

I want to compare two dates and based on the solution provided in link [How to compare dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java), I used the below code.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    String strDate1 = "21-01-2021";
    String strDate2 = "01-02-2021";
    Date date1 = sdf.parse(strDate1);
    Date date2 = sdf.parse(strDate2);
    if (date1.after(date2)) {
        System.out.println(strDate1 + " is after " + strDate2);
    }

    if (date1.before(date2)) {
        System.out.println(strDate1 + " is before " + strDate2);
    }

    if (date1.equals(date2)) {
        System.out.println("Both are same date");
    }
```

The output I get is `21-01-2021 is after 01-02-2021` which is wrong. Jan 21 2021 is before Feb 01 2021.
Can someone please help me to resolve this. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the wrong format for month. `mm` represents minutes. It should be `dd-MM-yyyy`

Also, another way to do the comparison is to use `date.compareTo(anotherDate)` which returns and negative value if date is before another, 0 if date = another and a positive value if date is after another.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this line as a SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy") will do the job.